# Creating my own "measurement unit/scale" in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I'm a web developer who occasionally does design work, though I'm trying to accomplish something else today.

---

I'm laying out a room and want to be able to create to-scale pieces of furniture. The room itself is 200" x 150".

Currently, I've made a document that I consider a "workable", 5x proportional size - 1000px x 750px. Each time I create a piece of furniture, I have to multiply the dimensions by 5 to keep proportion. That being said, you can imagine when converting multiple dimensions for dozens and dozens of pieces of furniture, it becomes a time-consuming process.

The simplest solution would be to just create a 200unit x 150unit document, that way no conversion needs to be made. But, replacing that "unit" with `px`, `cm`, `mm`, `picas`, or `points` either creates documents too small to work with, or too large to work with. Of course, zooming is an option, but then you run into scaling issues.

Is there a way to define my own scale? Or perhaps manipulate DPI so that a 50x50 square in Photoshop appears more like 200px x 200px?

I'm looking for a solution that only has to work on my monitor, not paper - this will not be printed. Using Photoshop CC if it matters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using illustrator, inkscape or some Cad application instead.

Comment: I have Illustrator as well, though truthfully I've never used it. Is this easier in AI? I was somewhat aware that photoshop wasn't exactly top-choice for this type of work, I'm just way more familiar with it so I figured it would cut time. **EDIT:** Realizing now that this would obviously be easier in AI because it's vector-based. Good call, I'll try that when I'm home!

Comment: Well youd have to use scale in ai too but its easier to use a cm vs meter scale and AI filesize does not blow up for empty space as like pixel editors do.

Comment: Well in AI, if I'm "creating" the furniture by simply creating rectangles *within* Illustrator, then wouldn't I just be able to use a 200px x 150px canvas and zoom in 500% without any distortion?

Comment: That's the very definition of working with vectors.

Comment: Illustrator does not have pixels and certainly no pixel canvas, just physical units and a fixed magick conversion unit to make them pixels. You can zoom quite much yes.

Comment: Well then it seems like this is properly solved. The solution in the end was right in front of my eyes, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question here:

This question from the onset was just a product of me thinking about things all wrong.

As pointed out by [joojaa](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa) above, a vector-based program like Illustrator would be a far better choice. Because I'm creating the elements within Illustrator, I wouldn't have to worry about any distortion when zooming in. That means I can make a 200 x 150 document and keep all items true-to-size. To make the document a workable size, I could simply just zoom 500%.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not to be printed, the phisical dimensions are totally irrelevant so the ppi informations is not relevant either.

It is a strange aproach because you are arbitrary asigning some pixels per furniture, meaning that you are asigning arbitrary pixels per furniture.

This would work for a pixel perfect game for example.

I totally agree a vector based aplication would be far better to use. But if this helps you can use the arrows on the keyboard to move one pixel at a time, but you also can press **Shift+arrow to move 10 pixels** your image. This means that you could use a 10x canvas, for example a 2000 x 1500 px and still having your 10px precision.

As another tip this means your document is at **a resolution of 10ppi**, or 10 pixels for each inch.

Comment: I appreciate the additional information!